# Game Center Can't Load Photos for several player IDs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, center

I am loading photos in a custom leaderboard recursively by using following code in a function:

```
-(void)loadPhotos {
 [((GKPlayer*)[players objectAtIndex:i]) loadPhotoForSize:GKPhotoSizeSmall withCompletionHandler: ^(UIImage *photo, NSError *error) {

            if (error != nil)
            {

                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            }
            if (photo != nil)
            {   

                [friendPhotos addObject:photo];
                [globalTable reloadData];
                i++;
                if (i< [players count]){
                    [self loadPhotos];
                }
            }
        }];
}
```

We are currently testing the app in two devices so we have 2 players in our sandbox environment. However first call for the first player loads the photo but the second photo, I cannot load, and I print the following error:

```
Error: Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=3 "The requested operation could not be completed due to an error communicating with the server." UserInfo=0x1b19f0 {NSLocalizedDescription=The requested operation could not be completed due to an error communicating with the server.}
```

Any suggestions?

Ps. Also tried it iteratively in a loop. Same error, and I thought it was due to I was making calls too frequently.

Comment: and players is an array of players which is initialized from the array returned from the GKLeaderboard request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible cause of this type of error is that you haven't enabled the correct port forwarding.  See [this Apple doc](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4307).